# How to map requests to an external directory

Tags: url-rewriting, linux, nginx

I have a directory/application that is located outside of the web root directory of my site.

Say the site is here:

```
/var/www/site/htdocs/
```

And the external app is located here:

```
/var/www/apps/coolapp/
```

My question is how can I configure nginx to map/route all requests that are like `www.mysite.com/coolapp/*` (asterisk being wildcard) to the external location `/var/www/apps/coolapp/`? For example, www.mysite.com/coolapp/test.php should server `/var/www/apps/coolapp/test.php`.

Per @krokola's answer, I tried adding the `alias` directive in the `production.conf` file that the main `nginx.conf` file includes. Here is what `production.conf` currently looks like

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate     /blah/blah/blah;
    ssl_certificate_key /blah/blah/blah;
    ssl_protocols       blah blah blah;
    ssl_ciphers         blahblahblah;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers blahblah;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/www.mysite.com-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.mysite.com-error.log error;

    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    root /var/www/site/htdocs;

    include conf/magento_rewrites.conf;
    include conf/magento_security.conf;
    include /var/www/site/nginx/*.conf;

    #-------CODE IN QUESTION-------
    location  /coolapp/ {
        alias  /var/www/apps/coolapp/;
        location ~ \.php {
            # Copied from "# PHP Handler" below
            fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
            fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
            fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
            rewrite_log on;

            # By default, only handle fcgi without caching
            include conf/magento_fcgi.conf;
        }
    }

    # PHP handler
    location ~ \.php {
      ## Catch 404s that try_files miss
      if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; }

      ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
      fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE default;
      fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
      fastcgi_param HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
      rewrite_log on;

      # By default, only handle fcgi without caching
      include conf/magento_fcgi.conf;
    }

    # 404s are handled by front controller
    location @magefc {
        rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?$query_string last;
    }

    # Last path match hands to magento or sets global cache-control
    location / {
        ## Maintenance page overrides front controller
        index index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @magefc;
        expires 24h;
    }
}
```

conf/magento_fcgi.conf looks like this:

```
fastcgi_pass phpfpm;

## Tell the upstream who is making the request
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_redirect off;

# Ensure the admin panels have enough time to complete large requests ie: report generation, product import/export
proxy_read_timeout 1600s;

# Ensure PHP knows when we use HTTPS
fastcgi_param  HTTPS           $fastcgi_https;

## Fcgi Settings
include                        fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_connect_timeout        120;
fastcgi_send_timeout           320s;
fastcgi_read_timeout           1600s;
fastcgi_buffer_size            128k;
fastcgi_buffers 512            64k;
fastcgi_busy_buffers_size      128k;
fastcgi_temp_file_write_size   256k;
fastcgi_intercept_errors       off;
fastcgi_index  index.php;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME     $fastcgi_script_name;
# nginx will buffer objects to disk that are too large for the buffers above
fastcgi_temp_path              /tmpfs/nginx/tmp 1 2;
#fastcgi_keep_conn              on; # NGINX 1.1.14
expires                        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set an alias.

```
location  /coolapp/ {
    alias  /var/www/apps/coolapp/;
}
```

Read more [nginx](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias)

**Update after comment:**

> Unfortunately, it's not working for me. I'm getting a 404 response
>   when trying to request www.mysite.com/coolapp/test.php when
>   /var/www/apps/coolapp/test.php exists

To understand why alias is not working, you have to take a look at how nginx processes a request: [request_processing](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

From the manual:

> Nginx first searches for the most specific prefix location given by
>   literal strings regardless of the listed order. In the configuration
>   above the only prefix location is “/” and since it matches any request
>   it will be used as a last resort. Then nginx checks locations given by
>   regular expression in the order listed in the configuration file. The
>   first matching expression stops the search and nginx will use this
>   location. If no regular expression matches a request, then nginx uses
>   the most specific prefix location found earlier.

If there is a regular expression that matches a request, it overrides static prefixes. In your configuration, when accessing /var/www/apps/coolapp/test.php, 2 locations match:

- location  /coolapp/
- location ~ .php

Because the second location is a regular expression, is overrides the first. But when you are accessing a html file eg: /var/www/apps/coolapp/test.html, if works as expected as only one location is found, the alias location.

In order to fix the problem with accessing php in alias path and override the default php location, you can add a nested location within the alias location, and do whatever you wish to do when calling php files in the nested location. In your configuration this would be:

```
 location  /coolapp/ {
     alias  /var/www/apps/coolapp/;
     location ~ \.php {
         Do whatever is needed
     }
 }
```

You can find an example [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/565425/nginx-alias-php-fpm-file-not-found)

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much. I'll give it a try later tonight and get back to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not working for me. I'm getting a 404 response when trying to request www.mysite.com/coolapp/test.php when `/var/www/apps/coolapp/test.php` exists.

Comment: Show us your config please

Comment: Alias must work, but you have the " location ~ \.php" which overrides the alias location when calling .php files. Please put a static html file inside /var/www/apps/coolapp/ eg test.html or an image test.jpg and test if that is fetched at mysite.com/coolapp/test.html.

Comment: Thanks a lot friend. I hope you get many vote ups for this answer. I'm very new to nginx. I'm only having an issue where nginx is now serving me the php files for download instead of executing them through php-fpm. I'm sure that is outside the scope of this question, so accepted your answer.

Comment: If ngix is offering to download instead of executing it is because you do not send the request to php-fpm. If you check the include conf/magento_fcgi.conf i am sure that you will find something relevant to this. For example: fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock; You should add this to alias too

Comment: For sure. There is `fastcgi_pass phpfpm;` in `conf/magento_fcgi.conf`, so I placed that in the nested location block. I also tried just including the magento_fcgi.conf file altogether, and both are giving me a 404 File not found for php files (I think from nginx), but not for image file. I tried putting the alias in the nested location, and that didn't help.

Comment: Show us magento_fcgi.conf :) And what you wrote inside the alias

Comment: Sure thing. I posted the updated alias and magento_fcgi.conf